# Errors when using JAXB to generate classes from portlet-app_2_0.xsd

Tags: xsd, jaxb, portal

I'm trying to generate classes for the portlet schema, found in http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd using JAXB (version 2.2.5) xjc tool but am getting the following errors:

```
c:\Tools\temp>..\jaxb-ri-20110512\bin\xjc.bat portlet-app_2_0.xsd
parsing a schema...
[WARNING] schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
  line 23 of file:C:%5CTools%5Ctemp%5Cportlet-app_2_0.xsd

[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xml:lang' to a(n) 'attribute declaration' component.
  line 759 of file:C:%5CTools%5Ctemp%5Cportlet-app_2_0.xsd

[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'descriptionType' is invalid.  Element 'attribute' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
  line 759 of file:C:%5CTools%5Ctemp%5Cportlet-app_2_0.xsd

[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'display-nameType' is invalid.  Element 'attribute' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
  line 781 of file:C:%5CTools%5Ctemp%5Cportlet-app_2_0.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: FWIW I just ran the XJC that comes with JDK 1.7.0_01-b08 with that schema without error.

Comment: Please make sure that from your machine you can access this URL: http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd - that seems to be what it is complaining about...